# python : Website Data to txt or xls

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am not so good in python, i am trying to get data from a website , The data in tables, i want this data in txt / xls,

I made a script but when my script go to the website, it work good until an entry come whihc have no data.

Webiste : bizearch.com

in this entry my python script stop: www.bizearch.com/company/Russell_Metal_Products_Inc_125558.htm

I am using CentOS, Python, BeautifulSoup.

my script :

```
#/usr/bin/env python
#
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

getInfo = ['Company Name', 'Contact Person', 'Company Address', 'Postal Code', 'Telephone Number', 'Mobile Number', 'Fax Number', 'Website', 'Business Type', 'Business Role']
flushData = {}

print "Company Name|Contact Person|Company Address|Postal Code|Telephone Number|Mobile Number|Fax Number|Website|Business Type|Business Role"

for Page in range(1,900):
    pageData = urllib.urlopen("http://www.bizearch.com/company/Electrical_Equipment~Supplies.8-%d.htm" % (Page))
    html = pageData.read()
    parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)

    for Row in parsed_html.body.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'ls'}):
        profileURL =  Row.find('a').get('href')
        profileURLHTML = urllib.urlopen(profileURL)
        profileURLHTML = BeautifulSoup(profileURLHTML)

        finalData = []
        for Details in profileURLHTML.body.find('div', attrs={'id':'yellowpage'}).findAll('tr') :
            if Details.find('th').text in getInfo:
                flushData[Details.find('th').text] = Details.find('td').text

                flushDataPrint = "%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s" % (flushData['Company Name'], flushData['Contact Person'], flushData['Company Address'], flushData['Postal Code'], flushData['Telephone Number'], flushData['Mobile Number'], flushData['Fax Number'], flushData['Website'], flushData['Business Type'], flushData['Business Role'])
        print flushDataPrint
```

---

I am new in this website, apologise if i miss something.

Comment: what happens when there is no data.. Does it throw any errros?

Comment: Russell Metal Products, Inc.|||||||Russell Metal Products, Inc., http://www.bizearch.com/company/Russell_Metal_Products_Inc_125558.htm|Buying Office|
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ashutosh123.py", line 22, in <module>
    for Details in profileURLHTML.body.find('div', attrs={'id':'yellowpage'}).findAll('tr') :
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: if you run this script , you might need to have a look on line no3 of script > from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: import depends on version of soup.. I thinks that's not the issue

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/3753691/user3753691 -- If issue is Nonetype: Check if data exist before processing or use try except block